# Open Source UML Tool which generates C++ code

Tags: c++, linux, uml

Are there any open source UML tools for Linux which can generate C++ source code?

It needs to run on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

[BOUML](http://bouml.free.fr/).

Moreover there is already a similar question [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212990/simple-c-uml-w-reverse-engineering).

Comment: bouml is not open source any more :-( http://www.bouml.fr

Comment: It's a pity I can't find an ubuntu download for the last release (4.23 ultimate patch 7) on the net any more. :-(

Comment: douml is a fork of bouml that has sources available http://sourceforge.net/projects/douml/

Answer (score 2):

According to the [UML Tools Directory](http://www.umltools.net/), you can add [Astade](http://astade.tigris.org/) to the above mentionned tools.

Answer (score 1):

[ArgoUML](http://argouml-cpp.tigris.org/)